# XML Serializing information on Base class and inherited class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am trying to serialize a C# object into XML so that it could be used as the body of API call.  They are very particular about the input they need. I have built the following class to hold the data I need to send over to them. Including attributes and all properties as Elements instead of attributes. They also require that lists include the `type="array"` I though that creating my own class the implements a List would be the easiest since all lists I give them must have the same attribute.  When serialization occurs it serializes the base class of List items but it doesn't include the attribute I want from the derived class.

```cs
public class CustomArray<T> : List<T>
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; } = "array";
}

[XmlRoot("message")]
public class MessageBody
{
    [XmlArray("Checks"), XmlArrayItem("CheckItem")]
    public CustomArray<Check> CheckList { get; set; }
}

public class Check
{
    [XmlElement("C_CHECK_NUMBER")]
    public string CheckNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("C_CHECK_AMOUNT")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("InvoiceList"), XmlArrayItem("Invoice")]
    public CustomArray<Invoice> InvoiceList { get; set; }
}

public class Invoice
{
    [XmlElement("C_INVOICE_ID")]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("C_INVOICE_NUM")]
    public string InvoiceNum { get; set; }
}
```

I then run this code:

```cs
// Create a sample object
var message = new MessageBody()
{
    CheckList = new CustomArray<Check>
    {
        new Check
        {
            CheckNumber = "111",
            Amount = 1.00M
        },
        new Check
        {
            CheckNumber = "112",
            Amount = 2.00M,
            InvoiceList = new CustomArray<Invoice>
            {
                new Invoice
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    InvoiceNum = "1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

// Create custom settings
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    Indent = true
};

// Serialize item and print it to console
using (var sw = new StringWriter())
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(message.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(writer, message, new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty }));
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
}
```

I get this written to the console:

```xml
<message>
  <Checks>
    <CheckItem>
      <C_CHECK_NUMBER>111</C_CHECK_NUMBER>
      <C_CHECK_AMOUNT>1.00</C_CHECK_AMOUNT>
    </CheckItem>
    <CheckItem>
      <C_CHECK_NUMBER>112</C_CHECK_NUMBER>
      <C_CHECK_AMOUNT>2.00</C_CHECK_AMOUNT>
      <InvoiceList>
          <Invoice>
              <C_INVOICE_ID>1</C_INVOICE_ID>
              <C_INVOICE_NUM>1</C_INVOICE_NUM>
          </Invoice>
      </InvoiceList>
    </CheckItem>
  </Checks>
</message>
```

But I need to get this:

```xml
<message>
  <Checks type="array">
    <CheckItem>
      <C_CHECK_NUMBER>111</C_CHECK_NUMBER>
      <C_CHECK_AMOUNT>1.00</C_CHECK_AMOUNT>
    </CheckItem>
    <CheckItem>
      <C_CHECK_NUMBER>112</C_CHECK_NUMBER>
      <C_CHECK_AMOUNT>2.00</C_CHECK_AMOUNT>
      <InvoiceList type="array">
          <Invoice>
              <C_INVOICE_ID>1</C_INVOICE_ID>
              <C_INVOICE_NUM>1</C_INVOICE_NUM>
          </Invoice>
      </InvoiceList>
    </CheckItem>
  </Checks>
</message>
```

Thank you for your help!

Here is a dotnetfiddle that I made to show it off. It's not exact but it has the same idea. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ALCX5H

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
[XmlRoot("message")]
public class MessageBody
{
    [XmlElement("Checks")]
    public Checks Checks { get; set; }
}
public class Checks
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Checks")]
    public List<Check> Checks { get; set; }
}

public class Check
{
    [XmlElement("C_CHECK_NUMBER")]
    public string CheckNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("C_CHECK_AMOUNT")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This will work but it will require me to have a new class for every list I use for this API.  I have another list that is embedded in the Check class and I was hoping to use one generic class every time. I have a feeling it is impossible after I have done more testing because the serializer is looking at the property to see if it implements IEnemurable and a generic and if it does it starts serializing the generic item and doesn't care about any of the other properties on the custom list class.

Comment: @JDB - you'll have to describe/give example of, what that extra "list" is. Depending on that, the above can be adjusted/extended.

Comment: Within a check item I may also have a `List<Invoice>`. With the above implementation I will have to have a class for wrapping about Invoices as well. I was hoping I could have a Generic special list class that I can just call anytime I need a list. It's not impossible to make it work it is just not the cleanest solution. I fear though that it may be the only solution so I can make it work.  I will edit the original question with another scenario.